# scrolling NSTextView leaves scrollbar in wrong position

Tags: cocoa, scroll, scrollbar, osx-lion, nsscrollview

I have an NSTextView inside an NSScrollView. I put text in the NSTextView and scroll it to the bottom programatically, which works OK, but the scrollbar stays at the top. Using the mouse to position the scrollbar causes it to jump to the bottom, where it belongs, and from that point it operates OK.

My code:

```
textView.string = s;
[textView scrollToEndOfDocument:self];
```

Don't get hung up on the scrollToEndOfDocument method--I also tried:

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(s.length, 0)];
```

and:

```
[[scrollViewText contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, textView.frame.size.height)];
[scrollViewText reflectScrolledClipView:[scrollViewText contentView]];
```

with exactly the same problem, shown here:

[image: Scroll bar in wrong position.]

I fixed the problem by adding one line:

```
textView.string = s;
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantPast]];
[textView scrollToEndOfDocument:self];
```

That runUntilDate call shouldn't be necessary. My theory is that it gives the NSScrollView a chance to catch up and synchronize itself, somehow.

This is all on Lion. I tried it with the System Preference set to both the Lion "backwards" scrolling and the the traditional pre-Lion scrolling, with identical results.

Any ideas about:

1. Why that call I added helped, and
2. How to make it work without that call?

Answer (score 3):

Try NSScrollView's `reflectScrolledClipView:`

Edit: How about replacing
`[[scrollViewText contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, textView.frame.size.height)];`

with

`[scrollView.contentView scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, scrollView.documentView.frame.size.height-scrollView.contentSize.height)];`

Because as it stands I believe you're scrolling past the document view's frame.

Comment: In my original post, I mentioned that I had tried that. No joy.

Comment: My comment above was made to a completely different response! Now that the response had been edited, my comment is wrong. I don't think editing should be used to change something entirely... only to correct an minor error. Otherwise the archival record is ruined.